# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list when using electron-builder

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I am pelease looking for help regarding electron-builder, using create-react-app and installing electron builder and running `node node_modules\.bin\electron-builder` always gives me this error:

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Comment: Kindly share your code

Comment: not sure what code to post, the only code I added for this was the basic electron setup, https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js

Comment: otherwise it is just an untouched create-react-app, I also tried this https://github.com/kitze/react-electron-example explained here https://medium.com/@kitze/%EF%B8%8F-from-react-to-an-electron-app-ready-for-production-a0468ecb1da3 and get the same error. I also get the same error when using capacitor to create an electron app from a create-react-app

Comment: the code where it is defined `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was running `node node_modules\.bin\electron-builder`. Adding electron-builder to an npm script worked.